# Maven Dependency version conflict : Elasticsearch and Lucene

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, lucene

My application uses Elasticsearch's transport client to connect to `ES 1.7.2` cluster. As per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-7-2-released), it uses Lucene 4.10.4, so below are the dependency versions in my application:

```
Elasticsearch : 1.7.2
Lucene : 4.10.4
```

Now, I want to use a lucene based library ([here](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak)) to perform in memory percolation. Looking into the `pom.xml` of this, it seems it uses Lucene 6.3.0 libraries. So, after adding this dependency, my application does not start up as Elasticsearch needs Lucene 4.10.4 and maven overrides it with 6.3.0, I have tried the following options:

- Searched for the earlier version of percolation library that is compatible with Lucene 4.10.4 - no success
- Tried making elasticsearch work with Lucene 6.3.0 - no success. I can try updating elasticsearch dependency version but my app won't be able to connect to 1.7.2 cluster with new version (also, I can't upgrade the cluster).

Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to exclude the dependency on lucene on your other library and hope that it works with version 4.x.

in your maven pom, do

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.flaxsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>luwak</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>[the lucene lib group]</groupId>
        <artifactId>[the lucene lib artifact]</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Technically, that's the way to solve version conflicts. But there's no guarantee that the application can be built.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried excluding `lucene-core` dependencies but it now throws `NoSuchMethodError` presumably because it's expecting a method which is not present in `4.10.4`. Anything else we can do to make it work?

Comment: Nothing, I can think of. The two libs, that you want to use together, seem to be incompatible because of their strong dependencies on different versions of lucene. Maybe get in touch with ElasticSearch and ask if an update is on their schedule.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I think you have a better chance backporting luwk to Lucene 4.10.4 than ElasticSearch to Lucene 6.3.0. If you're lucky there are just some minor incompatibilities.

Comment: @lexicore I have tried that. The very first version on luwak (1.0 https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak/blob/luwak-1.0/pom.xml) uses Lucene 5.0.0-intervals-1.2, so I don't think there is any older version available :(

Comment: @DarshanMehta I did not mean trying finding an earlier version, I meant backporting. Like forking, replaceing the dependendency and trying to make it work with Lucene 4.10.4.